# Xamarin.Forms: Relative Layout inside Grid layout not working properly

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, grid

I want to create dynamic grid layout with one row with 2 column and another row with only one column with colspan 2. 
And every column may contain on overlay image at top right corner.
For this i tried to add relative layout in grid layout but the issue is image tag in relative layout is not occupying complete width.
code to create relative layout

```
for (int i = 0; i < temp.Count; i++)
        {
            var data = temp[i];
            var framelyt = new Frame { CornerRadius = 4, IsClippedToBounds = true, HasShadow = false, Padding = 0, HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand, VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand };

            Image imageStack = new Image { Source = "placeholder_image1", Margin = 0, Aspect = Aspect.Fill, HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand };
             Image cmpltimageStack = new Image { Source = "completed_icon", Aspect = Aspect.Fill, HeightRequest = 32, IsVisible=true };
            RelativeLayout relativeLayout = new RelativeLayout { HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand, VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand, BackgroundColor = Color.Beige };
            framelyt.Content = imageStack;
            relativeLayout.Children.Add(framelyt, Constraint.RelativeToParent((parent) =>
            {
                return parent.Width;             
                }), Constraint.Constant(0));      relativeLayout.Children.Add(cmpltimageStack,
            Constraint.RelativeToParent((parent) =>
            {
               return parent.Width - 50;
            }),
            Constraint.Constant(0));
            gridStckActivity.Children.Add(relativeLayout, column, row);

            if (column == 1)
            {
                    column = 0;
                    isSingle = true;
                row++;
            }
            else
            {

                column = 1;
            }}
```

Comment: If I add image in RelativeLayout as your code, RelativeLayout in Grid's column, it image can fill the entire width, so can you post some screenshot here?

Answer (score 0):

It was working on android device properly but on iOS it was leaving some space on right padding. After adding x,y and width constraint it worked properly on both device.
Here is the revised code.

```
for (int i = 0; i < temp.Count; i++)
        {
            var data = temp[i];
            var framelyt = new Frame { CornerRadius = 4, IsClippedToBounds = true, HasShadow = false, Padding = 0, HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand, VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand };

        Image imageStack = new Image { Source = "placeholder_image1", Margin = 0, Aspect = Aspect.Fill, HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand };
         Image cmpltimageStack = new Image { Source = "completed_icon", Aspect = Aspect.Fill, HeightRequest = 32, IsVisible=true };
        RelativeLayout relativeLayout = new RelativeLayout { HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand, VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand, BackgroundColor = Color.Beige };
        framelyt.Content = imageStack;
        relativeLayout.Children.Add(framelyt, Constraint.Constant(0), Constraint.Constant(0),Constraint.RelativeToParent((parent) =>
            {
                return parent.Width;
            }));                    


relativeLayout.Children.Add(cmpltimageStack,
            Constraint.RelativeToParent((parent) =>
            {
               return parent.Width - 50;
            }),
            Constraint.Constant(0));
            gridStckActivity.Children.Add(relativeLayout, column, row);
        if (column == 1)
        {
                column = 0;
                isSingle = true;
            row++;
        }
        else
        {

            column = 1;
        }  }
```